# Differential equation $y'=2xy-x^2y'; y(-3)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Differential equation $y'=2xy-x^2y', y(-3)=1$

I've got the equation: $ln(y)=ln(1+x^2)+C$ where $C=-ln(10)$ and this is incorrectly.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Exponentiate both sides.

Comment: $ ln(y)=ln(1+x^2)+ln\, C \rightarrow y=C (1+x^2) $ Plug in BC

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your equation as
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy}{1+x^2}.$$
The general solution of
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x)y$$
is
$$y=Ce^{\int f(x)dx}$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.
Here you have
$$f(x)=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$
so the solution is
$$y=Ce^{\ln(1+x^2)}=C(1+x^2)$$
and
$$y(-3)=10C=-1.$$